# How to associate a custom object record to a user account

Tags: salesforce

In force.com I have created a **custom** object named **Sales_Agents**. Is there a way to specify that the users I relate here are associated to an real force.com ID ? For instance, how do I create a lookup to a real user under my tenancy account ?

Comment: Some alternative approaches include: 1) Creating a custom checkbox field on the User object and label it 'Sales Agent?'.  2) Creating a Role called 'Sales Agent'.  These approaches ensure that Sales Agents are real users in your system.  They also support lookup filters if you want to create Sales Agent lookups on other objects.  If Sales Agents are just users with no additional data, you may want to try one of these approaches.

Comment: thanks. good approaches indeed. I am starting to like force.com now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom `Lookup` field on the `Sales_Agents` object that relates to the `User` object. You cannot however make a custom `Lookup` field on the `User` object that relates to the `Sales_Agents` object.

This is a platform limitation.  There is an [idea on the IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007WKp) that you can vote up, but I would not count on it being available any time soon.

Here is how to add a `Lookup` field to your custom object:

1. Setup -> Create -> Objects
2. Select `Sales_Agents`
3. In the `Custom Fields & Relationships` section click `New`
4. Select `Lookup Relationship` and click `Next`
5. Select `User` and click `Next`
6. Complete all steps in the new field wizard and click `Save`